# A mutable pointer to a row in a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers

Assume there is a two-dimensional array

```
var myArray: [[MyClass]]
```

Since array is a value type in Swift, assignment like

```
let line = myArray[lineNumber]
```

will create a copy, instead of referring to an actual row.

In order to modify rows on an array (like inserting / deleting elements in a row) without copying elements and avoiding abundant use of indexing (i.e. having `myArray[lineNumber]` many times in the code), I tried C-style approach with pointers.

Assignment

```
let rowPointer = UnsafePointer(myArray[rowNumber])
```

doesn't appear to work the expected way, referring to `myArray[rowNumber][0]` rather than to a whole row.

However,

```
let rowPointer = UnsafePointer(myArray) + rowNumber
```

compiles without error and does the trick, so this way the whole row can be accessed by `rowPointer.pointee`

Since I also need to modify the row by inserting / appending elements, I tried mutable pointer:

```
let rowPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer(myArray) + rowNumber
```

However this assignment gives a compilation error:

Cannot invoke `initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' with an argument list of type '([[MyClass]])'`

Is there a way to access a row by a mutable pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can modify the actual pointer of your array but I am not sure if this has any real value over the existing array copy. Since, value types are always copied, so we get the pointer, change value and assign new value to the pointer.

But, it is better that you do it in usual way, considering array as a value type. Also if your class is reference type, it simplifies things a lot.

```
var myArray: [[Int]] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &myArray) { pointer  in
    print(pointer)
    var pointee = pointer.pointee
    pointee[1][1] = 10
    pointer.pointee = pointee
}
```

Comment: Great!  In my case I need to access a particular row. So I put: withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &myArray[rowNumber]) {pointer in ... } where (I hope) pointer.pointee is actually the particular row in the array, so I use pointer.pointee.insert(..) and pointer.pointee.append(...). Haven't got a chance to see how it works, but shouid be allright, given that it compiles without errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really tryign to achieve is add support for L values. Values that can be assigned to or edited in place. In Swift, that's achieved with the subscript operator:

```
struct Matrix<T> {
    var rows: [[T]]

    init(rows: [[T]]) { self.rows = rows }

    init(width: Int, height: Int, initialElement: T) {
        let rows = (0..<height).map { _ in
            return Array(repeating: initialElement, count: width)
        }
        self.init(rows: rows)
    }

    subscript(row: Int, col: Int) -> T {
        get { return self.rows[row][col] }
        set { self.rows[row][col] = newValue }
    }
}

extension Matrix: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral: [T]...) {
        self.init(rows: arrayLiteral)
    }
}

extension Matrix: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        let height = rows.first?.count ?? 0
        let rowText = rows.map { row in
            row.map { element in String(describing: element) }.joined(separator: ", ")
        }.joined(separator: "],\n\t[")

        return """
            Matrix(width: \(rows.count), height: \(height), rows:
                [\(rowText)]
            )
            """
    }
}

var matrix: Matrix = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "D"],
]

print(matrix)

matrix[0, 1] = "X"

print(matrix)
```

I would strongly recommend this over the unsafe pointer approach, which can lead you to all kinds of dangling pointer or buffer overflow issues. After all, "Unsafe" is right there in the name!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple version to show matrix with mutable [[Any]].

```
  let row1: NSMutableArray = [1,"22",3]
  let row2: NSMutableArray = [2,"33",3]
  let row3: NSMutableArray = [4,"4",5]

  let matrix: [NSMutableArray] = [row1, row2, row3] // Here matrix is an immutable. This is the difference from other answers.

  matrix[0][1] =  22
  matrix[0][2] =  "23"
  matrix[0][3] =  "2333"

  print(type(of:matrix[0][1])) //  __NSCFNumber
  print(type(of:matrix[0][2])) // NSTaggedPointerString
```

This is more important.

```
  let line1 = matrix[0] // here `let` again
  line1[2] = 33444

  print(matrix)  //matrix has changed. That means it is using reference.
```

Hope it's useful.

Comment: Indeed, NSMutableArray is a reference type, but it isn't generic, so you can't have an NSMutable array with specific type of elements.

Comment: It’s generic as it’s using any nsobject. It just missing a type check. But when you decide to use reference, you are risk in some way. This dry class is safer than a pointer.